# Maven block a specific repository

Tags: maven

I am developing a mybatis generator plugin, which have following dependency:

```
my plugin -> mybatis-generator-core:1.4.2:jar
                         | parent
             mybatis-generator:1.4.2:pom
                         | parent
                mybatis-parent:37:pom
```

in `mybatis-parent:37:pom`, it defines a repository like this:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>sonatype-oss-snapshots</id>
      <name>Sonatype OSS Snapshots Repository</name>
      <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
```

I am working in a environment without internet access, but we have a nexus server proxying maven central. as all my dependencies can be downloaded from our nexus server. I want to disable this `sonatype-oss-snapshots`.

I have tried overwrite it in my pom like this:

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>sonatype-oss-snapshots</id>
            <name>Sonatype OSS Snapshots Repository</name>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

and block it in settings.xml:

```
 <mirrors>
  <mirror>
   <id>xxx-maven-proxy</id>
   <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
   <name>Maven Proxy of xxx</name>
   <url>http://x.x.x.x:8081/repository/maven-public/</url>
  </mirror>
  <mirror>
   <id>sonatype-oss-snapshots-blocker</id>
   <mirrorOf>sonatype-oss-snapshots</mirrorOf>
   <name>SonaType OSS Snapshots Repository Blocker</name>
   <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
   <blocked>true</blocked>
  </mirror>
 </mirrors>
```

but maven still try to download from it:

```
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.codingfarm.fwx:fwx-sdk:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to sonatype-oss-snapshots-blocker (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots): Failed to transfer https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/codingfarm/fwx/fwx-sdk/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml. Error code 504,
```

it will not break my build, but I just hate any warning message, please help.

Comment: In a company environment, it is best to define a `<mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>` to your Nexus.

Comment: @JFabianMeier yes, we do that ,see my edits

Comment: Sorry, I don't see a `<mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>` in your post, just a `<mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>` or `<mirrorOf>sonatype-oss-snapshots</mirrorOf>`.